# Is it possible to define an application version in weblogic-application.xml?

Tags: java, xml, weblogic

Need to define a version of our product in weblogic-application.xml. Is it possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For WebLogic, the application version goes in the `Weblogic-Application-Version` attribute in the manifest file.

```
    <manifest file="${dist.dir}/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Created-By" value="${user.name}" />
        <attribute name="Created-On" value="${build.timestamp}" />
        <attribute name="Ant-Version" value="${ant.version}" />
        <attribute name="Java-Version" value="${ant.java.version}" />
        <attribute name="Weblogic-Application-Version" value="${project.version}" />
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I did increasing the manifest file and placing

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
Created-By: Ronald
Weblogic-Application-Version: v1
```

Create the manifest file in src / META-INF / MANIFEST.MF and placed in the file content. You can change the version by changing pro v1, v2 etc.

You can check the following link to see more details.

http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-set-ear-version-for-adf.html